# Showing list of bank in db on click of a button

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core

I have 3 input (username,password and datasource) and a button (connect) by clicking on button list of bank in db will be demonstrate

```
\[HttpGet\]
public JsonResult search()
{
//try  connect to make connection on sql engine
// if it could to connect get list of db and return
// that

            var username  = Request.QueryString["username"].ToString();
            var password = Request.QueryString["password"].ToString();
            var datasource = Request.QueryString["databaseConString"].ToString();
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            builder["Server"] = datasource;
            builder["Connect Timeout"] = 1000;
            builder["Trusted_Connection"] = true;
            builder["Integrated Security"] = false;
            builder.Password = password;
            builder.UserID = username;
    
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            Console.WriteLine(builder.ConnectionString);
    
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
            {    
                con.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(" **problem **SELECT name FROM sys.databases**"**,con))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                   {

// # I have problem in this loop **

                        while (dr.Read())    
                        {    
                            //list.Add(dr.GetString());
                            Console.WriteLine("{0}",dr[0]);    
                        }
                        //foreach(var item in list)
                        //{
    
                        //    Console.WriteLine(list);
                        //}                       
                    }
                    return  Json( JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }    
            }
        }
```

I do not know How use sqlDataReader and add object to my list

Comment: If you are new to all of this, I very strongly suggest you learn Entity Framework Core. It's MUCH easier than messing around with all of the extra code you need when using `SqlConnection` and related objects. Also, you get strongly-typed models, which makes your code much cleaner

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **problem **SELECT name FROM sys.databases**

Here you should also need to know in which table under the database, you are going to search `bank name` you haven't specified that. For instance, you should write like beloww:

```
SELECT BankName FROM BankTable [dbo].[BankDatabase]
```

> I do not know How use sqlDataReader and add object to my list

Well, you could fetch your **database-entity** from your **table** inside the **while loop**. Finally bind your **property** into your **list**. Your code should be as following:

```cs
        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult search()
        {
            var username = Request.QueryString["username"].ToString();
            var password = Request.QueryString["password"].ToString();
            var datasource = Request.QueryString["databaseConString"].ToString();
            SqlConnectionStringBuilder builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
            builder["Server"] = datasource;
            builder["Connect Timeout"] = 1000;
            builder["Trusted_Connection"] = true;
            builder["Integrated Security"] = false;
            builder.Password = password;
            builder.UserID = username;

            
            List<string> listData = new List<string>();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [BankName] FROM [DataBaseName].[dbo].[TableName]", con))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {


                        while (reader.Read())
                        {

                            string bankName = reader.GetString(0);
                            listData.Add(bankNamee);
                        }

                    }
                    return Json(listData);
                }
            }
        }
```

**Note:** Make sure `reader.GetString(0)` the order has followed accordingly. Means if the `[BankName]` is in first order theb it should be as `reader.GetString(0)`. In addition, remember the data-type as well. For your information, here, I am getting each bankNamee and binding to the list I defined above `listData.Add(bankNamee);`

**Output:**

[image]